Discord js gives me "DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message" when I put "async, await" in the script
When a user sends a fur file with "$fur2mp3",
the bot has to download it to the local repository,
convert it through an external batch script,
and send the converted file to a channel.
but an asynchronous problem causes the bot to run the script in the middle of downloading the sent file so display it as an empty file...
So I tried to solve the problem using await and async, but every time I do, I get this error
C:\Users\User\Documents\Discord-CommandLine-1.0.1\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154
      throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\User\Documents\Discord-CommandLine-1.0.1\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\User\Documents\Discord-CommandLine-1.0.1\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/(hidden channel ID)/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400
}

Node.js v20.16.0

The script is
commands.add('fur2mp3', async () => {
      const filePath = 'buffer_furrendering.txt';
    
    if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        msg.channel.send('Another file is being processed! Please wait!');
        return;
    }
        if(msg.attachments.first()){//checks if an attachment is sent
            //if(msg.attachments.first().filename === `fur`){
                msg.channel.send('Uploading...');
                await download(msg.attachments.first().url);
                msg.channel.send('Uploaded!');
                //msg.channel.send('d');
                msg.channel.send('Current Furnace Tracker Version : 0.6.5\nConverting started!');
                msg.channel.startTyping();
                exec('fur2wav.bat buffer_furinput.fur', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                    if (error) {
                        msg.channel.send(`Error during conversion: ${stderr}`);
                        console.error(`Conversion error: ${stderr}`);
                        return;
                    }
                    fs.readFile('buffer_fur2wavmsg.txt', 'utf8', (err, gwav) => {
                    if (err) {
                        msg.channel.send('Error reading conversion message.');
                        console.error(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log('gwav content:', gwav);  // Log content
                    if (gwav.trim()) {  // Ensure gwav is not empty
                        
                    } else {
                        msg.channel.send('The conversion did not produce any output.');
                    }
                    msg.channel.send({ files: ["furoutput.mp3"] });
                }); 
                });
                
    
            
        } //msg.channel. // 파이 이름 ㅍbuffer_furinput.fur'
               else { msg.channel.send('Send your file with this command!');
               return; }
});

I need to remove aw
ait and async from here to proceed without error (though of course nothing is converted)
is there a mistake?
edit: download() is
function download(url){
request.get(url)
    .on('error', console.error)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('buffer_furinput.fur'));

}

The question doesn't contain clear problem statement. What's download()? "I need to remove await and async from here to proceed " - it's very unlikely this is so. There's no sign this code should be synchronous. It's already async because exec() is async, it just doesn't use promises otherwise
